# Typescript object is possibly undefined error

Tags: typescript

In the following code, I have state objects called errorsLoaded and errors (a boolean and String array, respectively) and an api call to UseFetchErrors which return a String array and a true value when its done fetching errors:

```
1 const ErrorsPage: React.FC<ExecutionTableProps> = () => {
2     const location = useLocation()
3     // @ts-ignore
4     this.state={
5         errorsLoaded: false,
6         errors: []
7                 }
8     //@ts-ignore
9     this.state.errors, this.state.errorsLoaded = useFetchErrors(location.state.project_scan_id)
10    //@ts-ignore
11    if (this.state.errorsLoaded){
12        // @ts-ignore
13        return(
14            <>
15                <NavigationBar/>
16                <TableContainer component={StyledPaper}>
17                    <StyledTableName>Errors:</StyledTableName>
18                    <Table size="small">
19                        <TableBody>
20                                <ul>
21                                    {this.state.errors.map(o => <li key={o}>{o}</li>)}
22                                </ul>
23                        </TableBody>
24                        </Table>
25                    </TableContainer>
26            </>
27        )
```

Typescript is making me //@ts-ignore all calls of state objects (which I'm not sure how to get around in declaring multiple states). On line 21, I'm getting an "Object is possibly undefined" error that can't be suppressed with a //@ts-ignore. What's the best way to typify errorsLoaded and errors (can I do it with this.state = {...}) so I don't get these errors?

Comment: adding some logic like `{this.state.errors?.map(o => <li key={o}>{o}</li>)}` or `this.state.errors.length && {this.state.errors.map(o => <li key={o}>{o}</li>)}` doesn't fix it?

Comment: @FerToasted Nope for both suggestions

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NlvAeW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no *line numbers*, pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is being reported to have type errors because it has type errors. In fact, it has a number of very egregious errors.

---

First of all:

```
this.state={
  errorsLoaded: false,
  errors: []
}
```

You are using `this` in a functional component, which is not valid. That is the pattern for class based components. If you want to use state you must use the `useState` hook and store the result in local variables.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ errorsLoaded: false, errors: [] })
```

---

But, second, if you only have state for what other hooks are returning, then you don't need state at all. Just store the the result of hook and use it.

```
const hookReturnValueHere = useFetchErrors(location.state.project_scan_id)
```

---

Third:

```
this.state.errors, this.state.errorsLoaded = useFetchErrors(location.state.project_scan_id)
```

I think you are attempting to destructure the return value of `useFetchErrors` which returns an array of two values. However, this isn't the correct syntax because it lacks the `[]` on the left side, and you can't assign to properties of an object with this syntax (only newly declared variables).

So I think you meant to do this:

```
const [errors, errorsLoaded] = useFetchErrors(location.state.project_scan_id)
```

---

Putting all that together, here's a fixed version of what I think is close to what you want:

[(see playground)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCgeirgFoG7raBZFAayThgAsuwcAN2AATJCLhoIYuAHdo7CsAB2MJFEzouAUQAeSNAFcYwCMoAqKAEYAbJAAUcYAM5wA3gF8KYtDZRFJM2d4Q2ckABkINBQTMwAuOAAKAEo4AF4APnc4YJikBLc4AQgAKwMYAH1naOUK0QTgqBUAczgPNuZ6RgpvAz8AqWVguFCkADEkGDQebSgcKGcExPqcmCblZtTMuABtRpadgF0AGjgrCAg7FGVDnvJAofhZ+ed7FGb8xGIYADoxgGEADx6AzGUwWax2RwQFxZNJJLZZNwUOCo1GDYY2KIxcHpEZhSLRWLKFIotFwMlojHwHbqF6nOnQZyRFBiESHPGjCZTGZzJmJLFE8E-XJqH7FMoYKo1OoiZKUin3NHATBJRkLFls1LIpXk1FEGCGKAkhV6tGAww2DKms16tzq5w-EAoMCJCDpLKAmzAOCcACeaTcEA8GSDHkBVG9GWSXl1ttREct1rj5PlcdjCoNRuUcEBGQjyYzlHI1LgRGclvg8OBfIWbw+cCoGSAA)

```
 const ErrorsPage: React.FC<ExecutionTableProps> = () => {
    const location = useLocation() 
    const [errors, errorsLoaded] = useFetchErrors(location.state.project_scan_id)
    
    if (errorsLoaded) {
        return(
            <ul>
                {errors.map(o => <li key={o}>{o}</li>)}
            </ul>
        )
    }

    return <></>
}
```